# Checked baggage tag-through service via several airlines (ORD, PVG, BKK)

Tags: shanghai, chicago, air-china, pvg, china-eastern

I am flying to Bangkok from USA via stop over in ORD and PVG. In total I have three separate tickets:
American Airlines: ATL to ORD
China Eastern: ORD to PVG
Air China: PVG to BKK

Each time, I have 5 hours layover between flights, so I should have plenty of time to either pick up bags or just do carry on.

However, is it possible to do tag-through service via either all three or at least last two airlines (from Chicago at China Eastern service desk)?

Answer (score 1):

No. see https://us.ceair.com/en/transLuggage.html

It looks like China Eastern only interlines with Delta, KLM, Air France and China Airlines in Pudong.